# Memory exhausted while processing big size video using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, nvidia, semantic-segmentation

I am using a simple semantic segmentation network where I am using pre-trained models to predict the classes on the images. Everything works well on images and even small videos. However, the video file which I want to pass through the network and output a processed video is around 900MB. Whenever I try to use it, it can also process around 200 frames and then everything crashes with following error:

```
(0) Resource exhausted:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[327635100] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc    
         [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/while/body/_628/while/cond_1/else/_924/while/cond_1/norm/Sum}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

I am using opencv to read the video:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (1656, 949))
count = 0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, image = cap.read()
    # plt.imshow(image)
    if ret:
      print(image.shape)
      plt.imshow(image)
      image = cv2.resize(image, (1656, 949))
      image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  
      print(image.shape)
      plt.imshow(image)
    
      output = LOADED_MODEL(tf.cast(image, tf.uint8))
      panoptic_map, used_colors = color_panoptic_map(output['panoptic_pred'][0], DATASET_INFO, 60)
      dst = cv2.addWeighted(image, 0.5, panoptic_map, 1,1)
      print('Read a new frame: ', ret)
      count += 1
      #plt.imshow(dst)
      dst = cv2.resize(dst, (1656, 949))
      out.write(dst)
    
     
out.release()
cap.release()
```

On small size videos, everything works perfectly. When I check the GPU memory usage, its definitely exhausted. I have 1080 Ti with 8GB dedicated memory, in addition to 32GB RAM.

Is there anyway, I can process this video by saving parts on the disk and merge them later? Or any other way which can avoid memory overflow?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Currently, I am trying to force the video processing logic to cpu instead of gpu.
Forcing to cpu using `with tf.device("/cpu:0"):` also doesnt work. I still get the same error:

```
2021-09-08 09:44:02.367723: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1054] 1 Chunks of size 2772297216 totalling 2.58GiB
2021-09-08 09:44:02.367855: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1058] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 3.99GiB
2021-09-08 09:44:02.368003: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1060] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 6930300928 memory_limit_: 6930300928 available bytes: 0 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 13860601856
2021-09-08 09:44:02.368153: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1066] Stats:
Limit:                      6930300928
InUse:                      4285491712
MaxInUse:                   6300585472
NumAllocs:                      618063
MaxAllocSize:               3192342016
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2021-09-08 09:44:02.369071: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:467] **************__**********************************************________________****__________________
2021-09-08 09:44:02.369234: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1767] OP_REQUIRES failed at reduction_ops_common.h:186 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[346537125] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: debug this. split the code into ONLY video reading and ONLY pushing a frame (the same repeatedly) through the DNN. which part reproduces the behavior?

Comment: Thanks. It occurs regardless of the video processing. The network crashes after a while. I am not sure why. I am using deeplabv2 model without any modifications. Interestingly, if I choose input image size less than 1024x768 it crashes in the beginning itself. If I use higher size, it lasts for more time. More size usually means more RAM requirement, but here it very weird..

Comment: you should edit your question (and title) to remove everything that isn't required to reproduce the issue. "minimal reproducible example"

Comment: Don't see any Tensorflow related code provided in minimal reproducible example. Please provide the code snippet to reproduce your issue. Thanks!